# How to get different colors in python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Hi I am writing a python turtle file, where a function will return a random color (I can choose any three), and then a function will draw a face anywhere on the screen. It calls the function to draw a face 5 times, and each time it picks a different color. I have everything and it prints a face, but it will only print it in one color and I'm not sure how to get it to print a different color each time.

This is my code:

```
import turtle
import random

window = turtle.Screen() 

sam = turtle.Turtle() 
sam.pensize(3)

def getColor():
    color = random.randint(1,3)
    if color == 1:
        sam.fillcolor("pink")
        return "Color: Pink"
    elif color == 2:
        sam.fillcolor("lightblue")
        return "Color: Light Blue"
   else:
        sam.fillcolor("purple")
        return "Color: Purple" 

def drawFace(x,y):
    move = random.randint(1,2)
    if move == 1:
        sam.penup()
        sam.left(x)
        sam.forward(y)
        sam.pendown()

    else:
        sam.penup()
        sam.right(x)
        sam.forward(y)
        sam.pendown()

    sam.begin_fill()
    sam.right(90)
    sam.forward(10)
    sam.left(40)
    sam.forward(30)
    sam.left(50)
    sam.forward(90)
    sam.left(60)
    sam.forward(20)
    sam.left(30)
    sam.forward(10)
    sam.left(90)
    sam.forward(118)
    sam.end_fill()

    sam.penup()
    sam.right(90)
    sam.forward(50)
    sam.right(90)
    sam.forward(40)
    sam.pendown()

   sam.begin_fill()
   sides = 4
   while sides > 0:
        sam.forward(20)
        sam.right(90)
        sides = sides - 1
   sam.end_fill()

   sam.penup()
   sam.forward(60)
   sam.right(90)
   sam.pendown()

   sam.begin_fill()
   sides = 4
   while sides > 0:
      sam.forward(20)
      sam.right(90)
      sides = sides - 1
   sam.end_fill()



print(getColor())
drawFace(40,50)
drawFace(90,100)
drawFace(30,200)
drawFace(280,50)
drawFace(90,100)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getColor()` is only being called once, at the start of your program. You need to make a call to `getColor()` before drawing each face, like this:

```
print(getColor())
drawFace(40,50)
print(getColor())
drawFace(90,100)
print(getColor())
drawFace(30,200)
print(getColor())
drawFace(280,50)
print(getColor())
drawFace(90,100)
```

Your code would be a little more concise it you wrote that in a loop:

```
points = [(40,50), (90,100), (30,200), (280,50), (90,100)]

for x,y in points:
    print(getColor())
    drawFace(x, y)
```

Or you could put a call `getColor()` from your `drawFace()`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I know of how to do this, is if you do the starting code:

```
import turtle

draw = turtle.Turtle()

draw.speed(1)
```

And then the color

```
draw.pencolor("blue")
```